# Does a conversion by shapely.wkt.loads return the same polygon?

Tags: geopandas, shapely, wkt

One thing I can't explain. Why the `new` created polygon converted to string by `str()` or `.wkt` is not recognized in the list after `shapely.wkt.loads`? The last `print` returns no.

```py
import shapely.wkt

liste = frame["geometry"].tolist()
print(liste[:2])

item = str(liste[0]) # or liste[0].wkt
new = shapely.wkt.loads(item)

print(new)
print(type(new))
print('yes' if new in liste else 'no')
```

```py
#[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f8f8f24a880>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f8f8f25e070>]
#POLYGON ((39.32671165429348 25.18277937086028, 39.32671165429348 25.17460487673205, 39.31772850145229 25.17460487673205, 39.31772850145229 25.18277937086028, 39.32671165429348 25.18277937086028))
#<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
#no
```

the dataframe is big, I don't know how to put it in a copy-pastable example. It contains geometries in system coordinates 'epsg:4326'. The problem may come from the fact that the `tolist()` method returns polygons with particular identifiers.

Do you know what **object at 0x7f8f8f24a880** (for the first polygon in the list) means?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use my own data, and the last line of code returns 'yes'. Please post your real data + minimum runnable code.

Comment: @swatchai thank you very much for your help. I edited the post. Yes, following your suggestion, with a list of the type `list = [Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]])]` it returns well 'yes'. I think it comes from the fact of naming each polygon in list with `object at..`. What do you think?